# How to draw from multiple methods in Java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawing, graphics2d

Okay, so I'm trying to make a smiley face program, when it first starts up it's supposed to show the default smiley face(this part works and it's great I guess)

But then it should give you two buttons to pick from the smile and the frown buttons which should redraw the faces to show one smiling or frowning but it doesn't work for some reason.

I've been reading about graphics and I know you're not supposed to call them from outside the paint() method so I changed my code accordingly and I can tell the buttons are working because I make them print out something each time but the actual redrawing isn't working. I've tried using repaint() and revalidate() as well. For some reason if you use repaint() it repaints more and more each time which is odd, but maybe it's supposed to behave that way?

Can someone please take a look at the code and let me know what you think is the problem or where I should be looking for a solution I've used java for a while but I never use graphics :/ I've read your supposed to use setVisible/setSize(or pack()) at the end and that actually helped with some issues I had earlier but I don't get what to do when you want to draw multiple things most examples only show drawing one thing.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JSmileFacePanel2 extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

JButton smile = new JButton("SMILE");
JButton frown = new JButton("FROWN");

public JSmileFacePanel2() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("JSmileFace-V2: Jose M. Tobar");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(frown);
    add(smile);

    setSize(800, 800);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    //by default should show smiling
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillOval(200, 200, 500, 500);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(300, 360, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(600, 360, 50, 50);
    g.drawArc(400, 400, 100, 40, 180, 185);

    smile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("SMILE BUTTON CLICKED");
            drawSmile(g);

        }
    });

    frown.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("FROWN BUTTON CLICKED");
            drawFrown(g);
        }
    });
}

public void drawSmile(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillOval(200, 200, 500, 500);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(300, 360, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(600, 360, 50, 50);
    g.drawArc(400, 400, 100, 40, 180, 185);
    repaint();
}

public void drawFrown(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillOval(200, 200, 500, 500);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(300, 360, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(600, 360, 50, 50);
    g.drawArc(400, 400, 100, 40, 180, 185);
    repaint();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSmileFacePanel2 js = new JSmileFacePanel2();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still calling painting methods outside the `paint` method, because the `actionPerformed` methods different methods than the `paint` method. It doesn't matter that they are textually inside it, it's still a different method.

Also, you are repeatedly adding the action listeners every time that there is a repaint event, which will slow your application down to a halt and it will not repaint correctly either.

So, check whether you should smile or frown inside the `paint` method and add the action listeners inside the constructor.

The code then becomes:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JSmileFacePanel2 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // by default should show smiling
    private boolean doSmile = true;

    JButton smile = new JButton("SMILE");
    JButton frown = new JButton("FROWN");

    public JSmileFacePanel2() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setTitle("JSmileFace-V2: Jose M. Tobar");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(frown);
        add(smile);

        smile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("SMILE BUTTON CLICKED");
                doSmile = true;
                repaint();
            }
        });

        frown.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("FROWN BUTTON CLICKED");
                doSmile = false;
                repaint();
            }
        });

        setSize(800, 800);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(final Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        if (doSmile) {
            drawSmile(g);
        } else {
            drawFrown(g);
        }
    }

    public void drawSmile(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(200, 200, 500, 500);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(300, 360, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(600, 360, 50, 50);
        g.drawArc(400, 400, 100, 40, 180, 185);
    }

    public void drawFrown(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(200, 200, 500, 500);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(300, 360, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(600, 360, 50, 50);
        g.drawArc(400, 400, 100, 40, 180, 185);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSmileFacePanel2 js = new JSmileFacePanel2();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.  But, you're on the right track though.

Remember, you're running in an event driven environment, meaning that something happens and then you respond to it.

Painting should do nothing more then just paint the current state, in your example, every time `paint` is called, you're adding a new `ActionListener` to the buttons, so you could end up with 3+ `ActionListener`s attached to each of your buttons just when the screen is made visible, which will result in some seriously weird behavior.

You should also not modify the state of the component, directly or indirectly from within your paint methods, which may cause a `repaint` to be scheduled, this will result in your paint method been called repeatedly, which will eventually consume your CPU cycles, messy to say the least.

You should also avoid extending from top level containers and overriding `paint` (generally), preferring instead to use a `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent` method instead.

Two main reasons for this, first, it locks you into a single use case, meaning you can't re-use your components and secondly painting directly to a top level container like `JFrame` could have you painting underneath the frame's decorations/borders and because of the way painting works, even having the frames content painting over it.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

The general solution is to use a flag to change the way in which your painting process works and change this flag accordingly when you want to (from within the button's `ActionListener`s for example)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JSmileFace {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JSmileFace();
    }

    public JSmileFace() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new SmilyPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class SmilyPane extends JPanel {

        JButton smile = new JButton("SMILE");
        JButton frown = new JButton("FROWN");

        private boolean frowning = false;

        public SmilyPane() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            add(frown);
            add(smile);

            smile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    frowning = false;
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            frown.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("FROWN BUTTON CLICKED");
                    frowning = true;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillOval(200, 200, 500, 500);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(300, 360, 50, 50);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(600, 360, 50, 50);
            g.drawArc(400, 400, 100, 40, 180, 185);

            if (frowning) {
                drawFrown(g);
            } else {
                drawSmile(g);
            }
        }

        public void drawSmile(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillOval(200, 200, 500, 500);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(300, 360, 50, 50);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(600, 360, 50, 50);
            g.drawArc(400, 400, 100, 40, 180, 185);
        }

        public void drawFrown(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(200, 200, 500, 500);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(300, 360, 50, 50);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(600, 360, 50, 50);
            g.drawArc(400, 400, 100, 40, 180, 185);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

major issue: you're adding a lot of actionlisters in your code...

...whenever `repaint()` is called, it calls internally the `paint(Graphics g)` method and inside your paint-method you're adding a actionListener (again and again and again, whenever you redraw)

try to add the actionListener within your constructor:

```
public JSmileFacePanel2() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("JSmileFace-V2: Jose M. Tobar");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(frown);
    add(smile);

    setSize(800, 800);
    setVisible(true);


    //here:
    smile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("SMILE BUTTON CLICKED");
            drawSmile(g);

        }
    });

    frown.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("FROWN BUTTON CLICKED");
            drawFrown(g);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

a minor flaw:
don't call `drawFrown(g)` or `drawSmile(g)` inside your `actionListener` (you can't anymore, you don't know `graphics` anymore) instead call `repaint()`.

But before you `repaint()` you tell your graphic **what** will be drawn (i'm using an `int` for this, better use `Enums` but it will work for right now

i'm just doing the smile-part, the frown part is the same

```
private int style = 0;

public JSmileFacePanel2() {

    //other code as above
    ...

    smile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("SMILE BUTTON CLICKED");
            style = 1; //1=smile, 2=frown
            repaint(); //this calls internally the paint(g) method
        }
    });
}
```

and adjust your paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    //by default should show smiling
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillOval(200, 200, 500, 500);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(300, 360, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(600, 360, 50, 50);
    g.drawArc(400, 400, 100, 40, 180, 185);

    if(style == 1){
        drawSmile(g);
    }

    if(style == 2){
        drawFrown(g);
    }
}
```